# Run php from command line in 32-bit mode

Tags: php, linux, command-line, 32bit-64bit

Is it possible to tell php to run a script from the command line in 32-bit mode?  I have a php script that uses an ODBC driver that is only works when PHP is run in 32-bit.  Here is how I'm calling the script:

```
php -d safe_mode=0 -f checkImport.php
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The PHP interpreter is compiled either as 64-bit or as 32-bit. What you can do is compile or install a separate 32-bit edition of PHP on your system. How to do this is very platform specific.